# gulp-sassでのコンパイル時のエラーについて

Tags: gulp

gulp-sassを使ってSassファイルをコンパイルする際に

```
~/gluptest ❯ gulp sass
[15:46:37] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/gluptest/gulpfile.js
[15:46:37] Starting 'sass'...
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    node_modules/sass-graph/test/fixtures/d.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: e
       Parent style sheet: stdin
        on line 1 of stdin
>>@import "e";
  ^
```

というようなエラーが出ます。
**node_modules/sass-graph/test/fixtures/d.scss** には

```
@import "e";
```

と記述されており
確かに ***node_modules/sass-graph/test/fixtures*** 内には ***e.scss*** は存在しません。
どうすればよろしいでしょうか。

なお、gulp-sassは

```
sudo npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
```

でインストールしました。

また、**gulofile.js** は、以下のように記述しました

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

実行環境

- OS X 10.11.3
- node.js v5.7.0
- npm 3.7.5
- gulp CLI version 3.9.1 , Local version 3.9.1

Answer (score 1):

```
gulp.src('./**/*.scss')
```

この記述では、現在のディレクトリ以下の全てのscssファイルをコンパイル対象にしています。そのため、`./node_modules/` 内にインストールされたNodeモジュールの、テスト用ファイルもコンパイルしてしまってします。

自分のプロジェクトのファイルをgulp-sassなどでコンパイルする場合は、そのscssファイルを特定のディレクトリの中に置いて、そこだけを対象にコンパイルを行います。例えば・・・

```
.
|-- src //コンパイル元
| `-- css
|   |-- main.scss
|   |-- sub.scss
|   `-- ...
`-- dest //コンパイル先
  `-- css
    |-- main.css
    |-- sub.css
    `-- ...
```

という構造にしておいて、

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/css/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/css/'));
});
```

といった感じに指定します。この場合 `./src/css/` 以下の全てのscssファイルをそれぞれコンパイルし、`./dest/css/` 以下に出力します。